# LinearLayout (with onClick) containing ImageButton - is there a better way to solve it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

At the moment I have something like that:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="80dip" android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSettings"
 android:layout_width="80dip" android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" 
android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout has onClick listener attached to it.

**Problem:** When a ImageButton is clicked inside the LinearLayout, the event doesn't get triggered.

I could solve it by attaching the same on click to this button as I attached to LinearLayout. But in that case it would mean a lot of repetetive code (have many buttons).

**Question:** Is there a more effective way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the following tag to each imagebutton:
`android:onClick="yourOnClickFunction"`
Then, in your activity, add a corresponding function:

```
public void yourOnClickFunction(final View v) {
switch(v.getId()) {
     //Do whatever is necessary.
}
}
```

In the switch-block you need to know about the buttons IDs. You can get them via findViewById(R.id.aButton).

Comment: In addition to m1ntf4n's suggestion, I would get rid of the onClickListener attached to the LinearLayout unless it serves some other purpose.

Comment: And of course an android:id is required for each ImageButton.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ImageButton to an ImageView and you will start getting the click event

Answer (score 0):

You can write loop finding all buttons in layout and attach once created listener to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when the button is clicked, the LinearLayout's `onClickListener` doesn't fire. Which makes sense.

What you can do is put a `yourLinearLayout.performClick();` which will programatically fire the layouts onClick event. If you put it at the end of the buttons onClick then it will perform the buttons, then the layouts, in order.

Comment: Somehow it seemed to me to be more logical that when a parent has a onClick registered and child doesn't have, then the parents onClick gets transfered to child (inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

you must set the attribute `setClickable(true);`!!
you can access it in xml using `android:clickable="true"`